# c# console app error (The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception)

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I want to hit a url every 5 mins. I built a c# console app called myconsoleapp.exe and scheduled this in the windows task scheduler:

c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mypage.aspx");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
```

however I am getting this error? :

Error:

```
Application: myconsoleapp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Net.WebException Stack: at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at myconsoleapp.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: Does it run in the debugger?

Comment: Could you provide more details of the exception that occurred?

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes it runs fine

Comment: So wrap your code in a `try / catch`, catch the exception and display it on the console.

Answer (score 2):

You might get this error for various reasons such as:
- Timeout on web server side
- Name not resolving to an IP address
- Lack of connectivity to the Internet
- Invalid URL
- Other network or web site related problems
My advices:
- Get more info by looking at the error message in the exception
- Handle the exception so as to retry upon failure before giving up
- Investigate any connectivity, DNS resolution or any other network related problem